# Automate scp file transfer using a shell script

Tags: shell, scp

I have some n number of files in a directory on my unix system. Is there a way to write a shellscript that will transfer all those files via scp to a specified remote system. I'll specify the password within the script, so that I don't have to enter it for each file.

Comment: Can you please tell me if using a password in shell script with rsync worked or if you tried that? thanks.

Answer (score 104):

Instead of hardcoding password in a shell script, use SSH keys, its easier and secure.

```
$ scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa *.derp devops@myserver.org:/path/to/target/directory/
```

assuming your private key is at `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and the files you want to send can be filtered with `*.derp`

To generate a public / private key pair :

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

The above will generate 2 files, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (private key) and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (public key)

To setup the SSH keys for usage (one time task) :
Copy the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and paste in a new line of `~devops/.ssh/authorized_keys` in `myserver.org` server. If `~devops/.ssh/authorized_keys` doesn't exist, feel free to create it.

A lucid how-to guide is available [here](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

Comment: Even after following these instructions, I am still prompted for a password...are there other criterion that I am missing?

Comment: @ScottScooterWeidenkopf there could be a few things that could be wrong, like the .ssh dir or the authorized_keys files may not have right permissions (700).

Comment: @PradeepPati I figured out my problem. You're right, the problem was the permissions. In the link you provided, the author mentioned some permission changes. I made those changes, and now everything works.

Comment: Just to help avoid confusion with copy-paste usage of this solution, currently this answer seems to transfer FROM remote TO local -- which is opposite to what the OP is looking to do.

Comment: @Ciabaros good catch! I updated the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 44):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
spawn scp "user@example.com:/home/santhosh/file.dmp" /u01/dumps/file.dmp
#######################
expect {
  -re ".*es.*o.*" {
    exp_send "yes\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  -re ".*sword.*" {
    exp_send "PASSWORD\r"
  }
}
interact
```

http://blogs.oracle.com/SanthoshK/entry/automate_linux_scp_command

Comment: Note for windows users: The `expect` packaged in MSYS2 will match against the whole output, so the 1st rule will always be matched. If you exchange the order of both rules, you get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 25):

why don't you try this?

```
password="your password"
username="username"
Ip="<IP>"
sshpass -p "$password" scp /<PATH>/final.txt $username@$Ip:/root/<PATH>
```

Comment: Nice alternative to #!/usr/bin/expect -f

Answer (score 19):

you could also use rsync.  It seems to work better for multiple files than scp IMHO.

```
rsync -avzh /path/to/dir/ user@remote:/path/to/remote/dir/
```

**Update**

You can use rsync via ssh by adding the '-e' switch:

```
rsync -avzh -e ssh /path/do/dir/ user@remote:/path/to/remote/dir/
```

Comment: The nice thing about scp ist that it uses a secure channel. rsync does not.

Comment: You can force rsync to use ssh: 'rsync -avz -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir /this/dir/'

Comment: @flokra. Thanks, I was right in the middle of adding that update and got distracted.

Comment: This will still invoke an interactive password prompt. I believe the OP wanted a fully automated solution

Comment: @Dimitri scp -r copies files recursively. It has nothing to do with storing a password within the script and passing it to the scp call via a bash script! I don't really understand your comment.

Answer (score 10):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn scp -r BASE.zip abhishek@192.168.1.115:/tmp
expect "password:"
send "wifinetworks\r"
expect "*\r"
expect "\r"
```

Comment: Can expect be used for rsync? I am trying to do something and my RSA key method is not working. It keeps asking me the password for the remote machine.

Answer (score 5):

rsync  is  a  program that behaves in much the same way that rcp does, but has many more options and uses
the rsync remote-update protocol to greatly speed up file transfers when the destination  file  is  being
updated.

The  rsync remote-update protocol allows rsync to transfer just the differences between two sets of files
across the network connection, using an efficient checksum-search algorithm described  in  the  technical
report that accompanies this package.

---

### Copying folder from one location to another

```
   #!/usr/bin/expect -f   
   spawn rsync -a -e ssh username@192.168.1.123:/cool/cool1/* /tmp/cool/   
   expect "password:"   
   send "cool\r"   
   expect "*\r"   
   expect "\r"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are ok with entering your password once for every run of the script, you can do so easily using an SSH master connection.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

USER_AT_HOST="user@host"  # use "$1@$2" here if you like
SSHSOCKET=~/".ssh/$USER_AT_HOST"

# This is the only time you have to enter the password:
# Open master connection:
ssh -M -f -N -o ControlPath="$SSHSOCKET" "$USER_AT_HOST"

# These do not prompt for your password:
scp -o ControlPath="$SSHSOCKET" file1.xy "$USER_AT_HOST":remotefile1.xy
scp -o ControlPath="$SSHSOCKET" file2.xy "$USER_AT_HOST":remotefile2.xy

# You can also use the flag for normal ssh:
ssh -o ControlPath="$SSHSOCKET" "$USER_AT_HOST" "echo hello"
ssh -o ControlPath="$SSHSOCKET" "$USER_AT_HOST" "echo world"

# Close master connection:
ssh -S "$SSHSOCKET" -O exit "$USER_AT_HOST"
```

Answer (score 4):

What about wildcards or multiple files?

```
scp file1 file2 more-files* user@remote:/some/dir/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with ssh public/private keys only. Or use putty in which you can set the password. scp doesn't support giving password in command line.

You can find the instructions for public/private keys here:
http://www.softpanorama.org/Net/Application_layer/SSH/scp.shtml

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no file1 file2 file3 user@host:/path/
expect "password:"
send "xyz123\r"
expect "*\r"
expect "\r"
interact
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 quick ways of achieving this:

1. Using **scp**

   ```sh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   password="YOURPASSWORD"
   username="YOURUSERNAME"
   dir_origin="YOURSOURCEDIRECTORY"
   dir_destination="REMOTEDESTINATION"
   Ip="SERVERIP"

   echo "Uploading files to remote server...."
   sshpass -p "$password" scp -rC $dir_origin $username@$Ip:$dir_destination
   echo "File upload to remote server completed! ;)"
   ```
2. Using **rsync**

   ```sh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   password="YOURPASSWORD"
   username="YOURUSERNAME"
   dir_origin="YOURSOURCEDIRECTORY"
   dir_destination="REMOTEDESTINATION"
   Ip="SERVERIP"

   echo "Uploading files to remote server...."
   sshpass -p "$password" rsync -avzh $dir_origin $username@$Ip:$dir_destination
   echo "File upload to remote server completed! ;)"
   ```

**NOTE :**You need to install `sshpass` (eg by running `apt install sshpass` for deb like
os eg `Ubuntu`) that will enable you to auto upload files without password prompts

Answer (score 1):

here's bash code for SCP with a .pem key file.
Just save it to a script.sh file then run with 'sh script.sh'

Enjoy

```
#!/bin/bash
#Error function
function die(){
echo "$1"
exit 1
}

Host=ec2-53-298-45-63.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
User=ubuntu
#Directory at sent destination
SendDirectory=scp
#File to send at host
FileName=filetosend.txt
#Key file
Key=MyKeyFile.pem

echo "Aperture in Process...";

#The code that will send your file scp
scp -i $Key $FileName $User@$Host:$SendDirectory || \
die "@@@@@@@Houston we have problem"

echo "########Aperture Complete#########";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try lftp

```
lftp -u $user,$pass sftp://$host << --EOF--

cd $directory

put $srcfile

quit

--EOF--
```

Answer (score -1):

The command `scp` can be used like a traditional UNIX `cp`. SO if you do :

```
scp -r myDirectory/ mylogin@host:TargetDirectory
```

will work

Comment: This does not appear to address the Password.