# Can I use a scp to download a file using shell script

Tags: unix, scp

Can I automate a download of a file from a system using scp(by entering the user id/password) and manipulate the file and upload it to the same place. If you have any idea of using scp in a shell script, pls do let me know

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346509/automate-scp-file-transfer-using-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can automate that from a shell script pretty easily, but the question that remains is whether you want to input the password manually everytime you run the script or use ssh keys to accomplish authentication and achieve full automation.

Check [this tutorial](http://www.lesbell.com.au/Home.nsf/b8ec57204f60dfcb4a2568c60014ed0f/04eaff076bce249dca256fb6007f53e5?OpenDocument) on using SCP.

Answer (score 1):

Scp is ordinary command line uility in linux so it might be used directly. See [this page](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_scp.htm) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

use `ssh-copy-id` [the command varies by distro, but on Ubuntu it is ssh-copy-id]. here's how:
`ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub me@mysite.com` this will install your public key to the remote host. it will not ask for your password if you do this!
 If you have no ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, then run `ssh-keygen` and accept all the default options [just press enter when it prompts for input].