# Shell Script program to download files from linux remote server

Tags: shell, sftp

I am very new in shell scripting , i want to download some files from linux remote server ,so  how can i proceed for that.That remote server is ssh based .

Answer (score -1):

first of all, ftp service is better choice to get files from remote server.

If only sshd service is available, then you may use ssh based command `sftp` or `scp`.
However, using `sftp` or `scp` commands will invoke an interactive password prompt, which is a problem in shell script --> You have to ask for help to `expect` command. see [Automate scp file transfer using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346509/automate-scp-file-transfer-using-a-shell-script) .

Besides `expect`, you may also set up trust relationship between two servers, then you may use `scp` without password. See http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: 1) `FTP` is not a better choice than `SFTP`, what makes you say that? [`FTP` must die!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie) 2) Passwords can (and should) be avoided using public-key authentication (and an `FTP`-account would also typically be password-protected); using `expect` with `SSH` is bad advice.