# scp multiple arguments of bash script

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

I am trying to use `scp` to copy multiple files from a remote server.

I can successfully do it for a single argument as `script file_number`

Where `script` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Insert your username:
read user
scp $user@server:/path/run$1*.lz4 ./
lz4 -mdv --rm run$1*.lz4
```

All my files have the format: `runXXXXsubY.lz4`

This way I can copy all the files that have `XXXX==file_number`, but I want to pass multiple arguments, and copy all those files e.g. `script 1 2` to copy all the files with `xxxx==1` and `XXXX==2`.

I tried with:

```
scp $user@server:/path/run"$@"*.lz4 ./
```

But `$@` gets expanded without appending the `*.lz4`

I appreciate any help in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: It is fraught with peril and quoting issues, but you could do `scp $(printf "$user@server:/path/run%s.lz4 " "$@") ./`.  You're better off with xargs.

Comment: You're better off with a simple for loop calling `scp` once for each file.  There's not much benefit from calling `scp` with multiple args over calling it multiple times.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The problem with the `for` loop is that it asks for the password as many times as there are arguments. Which is something I want to avoid.

Comment: You should set up your ssh keys so that no password is required.

Comment: If you need to copy a *lot* of files, I would look at how to run `ssh` in master mode so that each `scp` can reuse the same authenticated connection for each transfer, rather than having to reauthenticate for each file.

Comment: In `zsh` (if you'll forgive the digression), you could write `scp "$user"@server:/path/run"${^@}*".lz4 ./`, which would expand the way you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that when the shell expands `$user@server:/path/run"$@"*.lz4`, it doesn't copy the `$user:...` and `*.lz4` parts for each argument, it just kind of blindly adds the list of arguments -- including word breaks between arguments -- into the middle. So if the args are `1` and `2`, it essentially expands to:

```
scp $user@server:/path/run"1" "2"*.lz4 ./
```

...so `$user@server:/path/run"1"` and `"2"*.lz4` are separate arguments to `scp`, which isn't useful. What you can do is create an array based on the arguments, and then use *that* as the source list for `scp`. Something like this:

```
sources=()
for runNum in "$@"; do
    sources+=("$user@server:/path/run${runNum}*.lz4")
done
scp "${sources[@]}" ./
```

And then use a separate loop for the `lz4` command:

```
for runNum in "$@"; do
    lz4 -mdv --rm run${runNum}*.lz4
done
```

EDIT: to avoid having to authenticate multiple times, you can open a master SSH connection and let all the `scp` transfers piggyback on that. Here's an example, based heavily on Felix Rabe's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346509/automate-scp-file-transfer-using-a-shell-script/24538331#24538331):

```
# Create the array of source file patterns to fetch
sources=()
for runNum in "$@"; do
    sources+=("$user@server:/path/run${runNum}*.lz4")
done

# Open master SSH connection:
# (This is the only time you have to enter the password)
sshSocket=~/"$user@server"
ssh -M -f -N -S "$sshSocket" "$user@server"

# Actually copy the files:
scp -o ControlPath="$sshSocket" "${sources[@]}" ./

# Close master connection:
ssh -S "$sshSocket" -O exit "$user@server"
```

Comment: This solution still requires me to enter the password for every argument in the script.

Comment: @user17004502 I apparently didn't test that part thoroughly. In any case, it can be fixed with a master SSH connection, see update.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet IMO is a simple for loop:

```
for xxx; do
    scp "$user@server:/path/run${xxx}.lz4" ./ 
done
```

If you do want to run a single `scp` (avoiding multiple password prompts is not a motivation for doing this; the way to avoid multiple password prompts is to setup your ssh keys so no password is necessary), you can use xargs:

```
printf "$user@server:/path/run%s.lz4\0" "$@" | xargs -0 -J % scp % ./
```

This does not guarantee a single invocation, and `xargs` will run multiple invocations of `scp` if enough args are passed that the argument string exceeds certain limits, but this should probably be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

One parameter substitution idea to build a pattern for the remote file names:

```
$ fn="$@"
$ echo scp "user@server:/path/run{${fn// /,}}*.lz4" ./
```

Assuming `$@` = `222 333` this generates:

```
scp user@server:/path/run{222,333}*.lz4 ./
```

**NOTE:** once satisified with the format remove the `echo`